# Predicting values in time series for future periods using RNN in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I found one article about [time series predicting using Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) in Tensorflow](https://github.com/JustinBurg/TensorFlow_TimeSeries_RNN_MapR/blob/master/RNN_Timeseries_Demo.ipynb).

In that article the test set is the last 20 values and the model predicts `y_pred` also for the last 20 values of the dataset and then calculates MSE of `y_test` and `y_pred`.

How can I extend the model to receive the prediction for next periods in the future (actual forecasting)?

Comment: The question is that whoever writes about Neural networks in time series prediction, make a prediction for input data in dataset. But how the prediction for future periods (not existing) can be done?

Comment: basically you can follow next article (you need output_size parameter) https://medium.com/@siavash_37715/how-to-predict-bitcoin-and-ethereum-price-with-rnn-lstm-in-keras-a6d8ee8a5109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first step you should use real values. Then using predict value to replace last value as you want. 
Hope the following code could help you.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, './model_saved')
    preds = []
    X_batch = last_n_steps_value
    X_batch = X_batch.reshape(-1, n_steps, 1)
    for i in range(number_you_want_to_predict):
        pred = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={X: X_batch})
        preds.append(pred.reshape(7)[-1])
        X_batch = X_batch[:, 1:]
        # Using predict value to replace real value
        X_batch = np.append(X_batch, pred[:, -1])
        X_batch = X_batch.reshape(-1, n_steps, 1)
```